# SQL stored procedure in one db called from another db. What is the context?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a question related to the context when calling a stored procedure from one database in the context of another database.

Say I have a procedure created in the `MainDB`:

```
USE MainDB;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_mainproc
    @Login   nvarchar(50),
    @Error   INT               OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- many details left out...

    -- Login as string must be captured in the xUser table to get
    -- the personal settings for the user...

    SET @_user_id = ( SELECT dbo.xUser.user_id
                      FROM dbo.xUser
                      WHERE dbo.xUser.login = @Login );

    IF( @_user_id IS NULL )
    BEGIN
        -- The user with the given @Login is not present. Indicate the failure.
        SET @Error = 2
        RETURN (1)
    END

    -- Do something in the MainDB. Here the main reason for calling
    -- the stored procedure is implemented.

    -- Indicate the success when finishing.
    SET @Error = 0
    RETURN (0)
END
GO
```

Now, I want to call the procedure from another procedure in the `AuxDB`:

```
USE AuxDB;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_action
AS
BEGIN
    -- Call the MainDB.dbo.sp_mainproc to do the action in the MainDB.
    -- The login name must be passed, and possible error must be checked.

    DECLARE @error   INT
    DECLARE @retcode INT

    EXEC @retcode = MainDB.dbo.sp_mainproc
                                  N'the_user',
                                  @error OUTPUT

    IF (@retcode <> 0)
    BEGIN
        -- Here the error must be signalized.
        RETURN 1
    END

    -- Everything OK, let's continue...

    RETURN 0
END
GO
```

My question is: When the `MainDB.dbo.sp_mainproc` is called from within `AuxDB.dbo.sp_action`, where the `dbo.xUser` table used in the `sp_mainproc` is searched for. Is the `MainDB.dbo.xUser` considered, or is the `AuxDB.dbo.xUser` searched for?

Thanks,
  Petr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Procs are compiled, so it will refer to the object in the same database in which the `dbo.sp_mainproc` exists, because when the proc was created, it refers only to `dbo.xUser`,  which doesn't have a database name part

(i.e. `MainDB.dbo.sp_mainproc` will use `MainDB.dbo.xUser` irrespective of which database that the proc is called from).

Comment: Thanks! The reason for asking is that the user is not detected in my case. Being a beginner, I wanted to ensure the bug is not in the part. Thanks again and have a good time.